# datepickerdialog theme_holo_light not displayed correctly in Samsung J7 Core

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-datepicker

I use java code to display datepickerdialog with a theme THEME_HOLO_LIGHT.
My compiled SDK version is 27. The theme is displayed perfectly in an oppo device (Nougat 7.0). However, in samsung J7 Core, the output is a different THEME.

[Sample output of THEME_HOLO_LIGHT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpno7.png)

The result of an output in Samsung is THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK.

I want the THEME_HOLO_LIGHT to display. Please help.

```
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            USERBIRTHDATE = dateFormat.format(new Date(year - 1900, month, dayOfMonth));
            dateTxt.setText(USERBIRTHDATE);
            flag = true;
        }
    }, 1997, 0, 01);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT` write `android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light`.

If this doesn't work, replace it with this:

```
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {..}
```

Comment: i have added code snippet to my code, mind reading it or show me how to use your code?

Comment: thanks, i have not tried it to samsung j7 core but the result it gave to oppo is different. it shift the datepickerdialog to top instead at the center

Comment: also, ContextWrapper gives me an error ContextWrapper cannot be applied (RegisterData, int)

Comment: Don't you use it in an activity?

Comment: i am, i put it inside onCreate(bundle) method

Comment: Ok then use android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light on your samsung device

Comment: Did you use `ContextThemeWrapper` (not ContextWrapper) like the code above? See my edited answer

Comment: yes i did, the error is cannot be applied to context, themeResId, listener, year, monthOfyear, dayOfMonth. the problem resides with themeResId

Comment: I can't see where the problem is with ContextThemeWrapper. It works fine with me. Anyway test it with android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light

Comment: done testing the samsung J7 Core and it still displays the default theme.